# What monad style typeclass does this typeclass fit into?

Tags: haskell, monads, category-theory

I've got a type `t` that supports the following three operations:

```
extract :: t a -> a
duplicate :: t a -> t (t a)
(<*>) :: t (a -> b) -> t a -> t b
```

Naturally I can also write bind:

```
(>>=) :: f a -> (a -> f b) -> f b
(>>=) x f = f (extract x)
```

And `join`:

```
join :: t (t a) -> t a
join = extract
```

But I can't write `fmap` nor `pure`

So this is kind of a "monad", and kind of a "comonad", but without `fmap`.

Technically, I have got an `fmap` and `pure`, but they're constrained.

I looked at various constrained functor style packages, but they all seem to constrain `(<*>)` as well, but in my case `(<*>)` is not constrained.

Is there an existing typeclass I could squeeze this type into?

*If anyone is interested, the actual type I'm dealing with is the [`Closure`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/static-closure-0.1.0.0/docs/Control-Static-Closure.html#t:Closure) type*

Comment: Without `fmap`, I don't know of any standard typeclasses.

Comment: It looks a lot like [ComonadApply](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad/docs/Control-Comonad.html), but that requires that the container is a `Functor`.

Comment: Anything is a `Functor` with [`Coyoneda`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.1/docs/Data-Functor-Coyoneda.html) (`instance Functor (Coyoneda f)`)

Comment: This reminds me of things like [`DeepArrow`](https://wiki.haskell.org/DeepArrow), which tries to get as much of the structure of an arrow as possible without requiring `arr` (which is the analogue of `fmap`).

Comment: @Iceland_jack unfortunately this probably doesn't help in my case as there's no way to go back from a `Coyoneda` to the original type unless the original type is itself a `Functor`, which in this case it isn't.